# How to use nsq as a broker for the ELK stack (ElasticSearch+LogStash+Kibana)

Tags: elasticsearch, nsq, elastic-stack

I am trying to use nsq as a broker for the [ELK stack](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elkdownloads/).

I was thinking of doing this by having [nsq](http://nsq.io/) send data to [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) via the REST [api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).  According to that doc, I can make an HTTP PUT request to add data to elastic search.

But, according the nsq [doc](http://nsq.io/components/utilities.html), nsq can only make a POST or GET request via the nsq_to_http utility.  I can't make a PUT request which elasticsearch requires. How can I pass values from nsq to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the nsq_to_file utility and then use logstash to post the files. For anything further you would need to look at the code to adapt it to what you want.